# Get Column Names as Symbols in Julia DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a `DataFrame`

```
df = DataFrame(a=1:4,b=5:8, c=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c      
     │ Int64  Int64  String 
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │     1      5  a
   2 │     2      6  b
   3 │     3      7  c
   4 │     4      8  d
```

I can get the column names as a `Vector` of `String`s with

```
names(df)
3-element Vector{String}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"
```

Is there a built-in way of getting it as `Symbol`s? (I thought, I've seen this somewhere, but I can't remember where...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `propertynames` from Base Julia to get what you want:

```
julia> propertynames(df)
3-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :a
 :b
 :c
```